# Como corrigir o erro "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Config' not found"

Tags: php, docker, phalcon-php

Estou tentando iniciar os estudos do framework phalcon, e como costume, estou criando um dockerfile para ele.
Fiz toda instalação, mas ao tentar utilizar o comando de criação de projeto ou alguns outros comandos (a não ser o de info), fica exibindo erro

```
root@application-hsh:/var/www/html# phalcon create-project test

Phalcon DevTools (4.2.0)


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Config' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/src/Builder/Component/AbstractComponent.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/src/Commands/Builtin/Project.php(74): Phalcon\DevTools\Builder\Component\AbstractComponent->__construct(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/src/Script.php(109): Phalcon\DevTools\Commands\Builtin\Project->run(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/src/Script.php(148): Phalcon\DevTools\Script->dispatch(Object(Phalcon\DevTools\Commands\Builtin\Project))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/phalcon(65): Phalcon\DevTools\Script->run()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/src/Builder/Component/AbstractComponent.php on line 48
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer

FROM php:7.4.30-fpm-buster
LABEL maintainer='foo bar <foo@bar.com>'
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update --yes
RUN apt-get install --yes
RUN apt-get install --yes autoconf
RUN apt-get install --yes git
RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN apt-get install --yes zip
RUN apt-get install --yes wget
RUN apt-get install --yes gettext
RUN pecl install phalcon
RUN apt-get install --yes libpcre3-dev
#RUN apt-get install --yes php7-dev
#RUN apt-get install --yes php7-mysql
RUN apt-get install --yes gcc

RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | bash

RUN git clone --depth=1 "https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git" && cd cphalcon/build && ./install
RUN git clone --depth=1 "https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git" && cd phalcon-devtools && ./phalcon.sh

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    mysqli \
    pdo \
    pdo_mysql
RUN echo 'alias phalcon="/var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/phalcon"' >> ~/.bashrc
# Fix Timezone America/Sao_Paulo
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo

# Time Zone && Memory Limit
RUN echo "memory_limit=-1" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/memory-limit.ini \
    && echo "date.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/date_timezone.ini

RUN apt-get clean -y
```

Comment: O erro ocorre porque a versão utilizada sofreu uma alteração. A classe *Config* mudou de *Phalcon\Config* na 4.x para *Phalcon\Config\Config*, na 5.x. **Dicas:** **1)** Instale via *pecl*, o branch master do Git do Phalcon pode conter falhas, pois está em desenvolvimento. **2)** Utilize a versão 4.x do framework, ela é a última versão estável; **3)** Evite criar layers desnecessárias em seu Dockerfile (dá para executar os comandos apt-get update e install na mesma layer (= RUN); **4)** Não faz sentido instalar duas versões do Phalcon (via packagecloud e git)

Comment: obrigado pelas informações @ValdeirPsr.
Tem mais do que uma pq estava no meio do teste quando parei para escrever aqui.
Vou far uma olhada na doc para ver como instalar via pecl.
Quanto aos vários RUNs, entendo que boa parte não precisa mesmo, é costume meu fazer assim para testar o que quebra na instalação, e depois que tudo rodar, aí sim eu volto e faço a refatoração disso. 
Obrigado pelo seu tempo. Assim que conseguir testar, mando um feedback

Answer (score -2):

Com o comentário do "Valdeir Psr", consegui me atentar melhor a instalação no Dockerfile.

Código funcionando:

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer

FROM php:7.4.30-fpm-buster
LABEL maintainer='foo bar <foo@bar.com>'
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update --yes
RUN apt-get install --yes
RUN apt-get install --yes autoconf \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    wget \
    gettext \
    libpcre3-dev \
    gcc
RUN pecl install phalcon


RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    mysqli \
    pdo \
    pdo_mysql
RUN echo 'alias phalcon="/var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools/phalcon"' >> ~/.bashrc
# Fix Timezone America/Sao_Paulo
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo

# Time Zone && Memory Limit
RUN echo "memory_limit=-1" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/memory-limit.ini \
    && echo "date.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/date_timezone.ini

RUN apt-get clean -y
```